# How to append a value to an array in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array

I have a formula, which returns an array. I would like to append another value to this array. Is there any way to do this with a formula without VBA in Excel?

e.g.

`{1, 2, 3}` -> `{1, 2, 3, 4}`

or perhaps

`{1, 2, 3}` and `{4, 5}` -> `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`

I am trying to move an item in an array to the end of the array. e.g.
`{1, 4, 2, 3, 4}` -> `{1, 2, 3, 4}`

I have managed to remove the item with FILTER function.
`=FILTER({1, 4, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 4, 2, 3, 4} <> 4)`
Now, next step would be to append the value back to the array. This part of appending a value can be useful for other reasons as well. That's why, I asked specifically for this problem.

Comment: This seems to be an X:Y problem.  Can you describe the whole problem?  What you start with and what you want in the end.  Seems to me we are missing steps.  There may be a better way.

Comment: It is as simple as it gets, I want to append to an array. I want my array to end with a specified value. Actually, this value was in the array and I can filter it out with FILTER function. Now, I want to put it in the end of the array. Honestly, I can't believe that Excel doesn't have a function for this.

Comment: Even though I answered, I believe that if we know what you started with, the data before the filter and what you want to end up with we could find an easier method.

Comment: Your answer is perfect and easy. I have been looking for an hour and couldn't find an easier way to append values to an array in Excel or concatenate 2 arrays. My question was a as general and specific as it can be. My experience is that too specific questions tend to specific solutions, which don't work in other scenarios. Your solution now, does. I add some more description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Office 365 we can use LET to help shorten the formula:

```
=LET(
    arry1,    {1,2,3},
    arry2,    {4,5},
    cnt,      COUNTA(arry1),
    seq,      SEQUENCE(,cnt+COUNTA(arry2)),
    IF(seq>cnt,INDEX(arry2,,seq-cnt),INDEX(arry1,,seq)))
```

It basically uses Sequence to move across the first array till it is larger than the  number of items, then it switches to the second array.

[image]

Comment: Perfect. I had to also find out about vertical and horizontal array delimiters to correctly adapt to European Excel localization. In this case array delimiter "\" instead of ";".

Comment: Is there a difference with this formula and Excel for macOS? I get with this formula "=LET(
    arry1;    {1;2;3};
    arry2;    {4;5};
    cnt;      COUNTA(arry1);
    seq;      SEQUENCE(;cnt+COUNTA(arry2));
    IF(seq>cnt;INDEX(arry2;;seq-cnt);INDEX(arry1;;seq)))"
in cell B1,C1 en E1 the #ref! error

Comment: Forgot to type;
 If I do a F9 ( show results ) for arry1 and arry2, I see only the 1 or 4. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I solved it with `VSTACK`/`HSTACK` in the following way:

```
=VSTACK(SORT(UNIQUE(B1:B7&"")), "test1", "test2")
```

this will take all the unique values between `B1` and `B7`, will sort them (and return an array) and will append at the end the two items `tes1` and `test2`

Note: the `&""` is added to have an empty string for blank lines instead of `0`